# IntelliJ Typescript intellisence for union types

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

I am using Typescript and IntelliJ.
This is the code I have:

```
import { Shop, VoucherTestData } from '../types/types';
import voucherActions from '../actions/common/voucher-actions';
import { CheckoutActionsCats } from '../actions/cats/checkout-actions';
import { CheckoutActionsDogs } from '../actions/dogs/checkout-actions';

export function testVoucher(data: VoucherTestData) {
  context(`${data.shop}`, function () {
    const checkoutActions =
      data.shop === Shop.CATS ? <CheckoutActionsCats>data.checkoutActions : <CheckoutActionsDogs>data.checkoutActions;

    describe('Redeem voucher as a guest user', function () {
      it('I can redeem valid voucher', function () {
        checkoutActions.landOnCheckoutPageAsGuest(checkoutGuestModel);
        voucherActions.saveCheckoutPricesBeforeApplyingVoucher();

        voucherActions.redeemVoucher(voucher);
        voucherActions.verifyVoucherApplied(voucher);

        checkoutActions.finalizeOrder();
        checkoutActions.verifyCheckoutThankYouPage();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

`CheckoutActionsCats` and `CheckoutActionsDogs` extend from `CheckoutActions`.
When I hover over `checkoutActions` variable I can see that it is of union type `CheckoutActionsCats | CheckoutActionsDogs`.
But when I hover over the method, e.g. `landOnCheckoutPageAsGuest` then it says union type but only shows `CheckoutActionsCats` implementation.
Also if I do CTRL + click to enter the method implementation it throws me to `CheckoutActionsCats`.
And the method `CheckoutActionsDogs.landOnCheckoutPageAsGuest` is shown as unused in the `CheckoutActionsDogs` class.
This is strange behavior to me.
I would expect that on hover I can see both implementations listed so that I can go to the one or the other.
Also, I would expect that the method `CheckoutActionsDogs.landOnCheckoutPageAsGuest` is not shown as unused since I am kinda using it here in my test.
Is there a way to make IntellJ behave as I expect it to behave? Or do I need to make some changes to my code?
Thanks!

[EDIT]
These are the definitions of the used types.
`CheckoutActions` parent class

```
export class CheckoutActions {

  changeAddress(changeAddressText: string) {
    cy.get('[data-cy="btnChangeAddress"]').first().should('be.visible').should('have.text', changeAddressText).click();
    cy.get('[data-cy="btnChooseAddress"]').eq(1).should('be.visible').click();
  }

  // ... other common methods here
}
```

`CheckoutActionsCats` child class

```
import { CheckoutGuestModel, PaymentMethod} from '../../types/types';
import { CheckoutActions } from '../common/checkout-actions';
import addToCartActions from './addToCart-actions';

export class CheckoutActionsCats extends CheckoutActions {
  // other methods here
  landOnCheckoutPageAsGuest(checkoutGuestModel: CheckoutGuestModel) {
    addToCartActions.navigateToCheckoutWithProductFlow(
      checkoutGuestModel.url,
      checkoutGuestModel.product,
      checkoutGuestModel.toCheckoutButtonText,
      checkoutGuestModel.threshold
    );
    this.navigateToGuestCheckout();
    this.fillOutAddressData(checkoutGuestModel.userAddressData, false);
    this.insertBirthday(checkoutGuestModel.userAddressData.birthday);
    this.selectPaymentMethod(PaymentMethod.CashInAdvance);
  }
}

export default new CheckoutActionsCats();
```

`CheckoutActionsDogs` child class

```
import { CheckoutGuestModel} from '../../types/types';
import { CheckoutActions } from '../common/checkout-actions';
import addToCartActions from './addToCart-actions';

export class CheckoutActionsDogs extends CheckoutActions {
// other methods here  
landOnCheckoutPageAsGuest(checkoutGuestModel: CheckoutGuestModel) {
    addToCartActions.navigateToCheckoutWithProductFlow(
      checkoutGuestModel.url,
      checkoutGuestModel.product,
      checkoutGuestModel.toCheckoutButtonText,
      checkoutGuestModel.threshold
    );
    this.navigateToGuestCheckout();
    this.fillOutAddressData(checkoutGuestModel.userAddressData);
    this.insertBirthday(checkoutGuestModel.userAddressData.birthday);
    this.selectCashInAdvance();
  }
}

export default new CheckoutActionsDogs();
```

Comment: Please attach the definitions for the relevant types you have defined.

Comment: @Mack is this what u meant? I have edited my question.

Comment: It's a bit strange to use a union type of the child classes - it mixes two different types of polymorphism together. If you want to use class-based inheritance here, I'd make the base class abstract and add a signature for the `landOnCheckoutPageAsGuest` method, then use the base class as the type instead of a union of all possible children.

Comment: @Mack Thanks! I will use that instead (makes more sense I guess). When would it be appropriate to use union type? Can you give an realistic example? Please post it as a answer so I can accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd generally use classes to solve a problem like this when all child types (subclasses) will generally have the same interface or shape (and the implementation for each function in that interface is the same for all instances of a particular type e.g. every `Dog` `bark()`s the same. Unions are more broad and give you polymorphism of a different type when using something like the Discriminated Union pattern. Each individual object can define it's own implementation.